# how to make json object from relational models in django

Tags: python, json, django

I have a model which has all fields as foreign keys. I want to make a relational query on my model > Resources, so that i can access the attributes of other models like Riggs or Pluto in my example and make a json object which i can send over to my template.

```
class Resources (models.Model):

   tag = models.CharField(max_length=60)
   sans_id = models.ForeignKey(Sans, null=True,blank=True)
   riggs_id = models.ForeignKey(Riggs, null=True,blank=True)
   crocs_id = models.ForeignKey(Crocs, null=True,blank=True)
   pluto_id = models.ForeignKey(Pluto, null=True, blank=True)
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(Users, null=True, blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.tag)
```

I want to access properties of relational objects in the following way. but i don't know which properties i may require in different cases so i want a complete relational object as json so that i can access any given field.

```
for x in Resources.objects.all()
    x.crocs_id.specifications
    x.pluto_id.flag
    x.pluto_id.settings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow all the foreign key relationships by using the [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) method without specifying any arguments.

```
for x in Resources.objects.select_related():
    # do something
```

But be advised, that this will result in a complex query if your database table has a lot of rows.

Comment: thank you. But select_related() doesn't give me a complete object object when i serialize and send it back as json. I can't iterate on related model as i only have FK values.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a dict like of

```
b = {}
for a in Resource.objects.all():
    for i in a:
        b[str(i)] = i
```

and the finally you can use json.dumps() as

> result = json.dumps(b) and pass around anywhere

the b will be a dict of the form with keys with the name of your models and each key corresponds to the related model so you can access it like say

> b['crocs_id'].(Any of your Crocs attribute)

I think this should work................

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
resources= Resources.objects.values('tag', 'crocs_id__specifications', 'pluto_id__flag', 'pluto_id__settings')

json_data= json.dumps([item for item in resources])
```